# OSX find and sed not being called on every file that matches

Tags: bash, macos, replace, sed, find

First, my problem:

I have thousands of test files that currently call a function inside of another function. This could be placed anywhere in the file but can only be called once. The structure is as follows:

`md = mod.solver(mod,TestFunctionCall());`

I need to replace the function call `TestFunctionCall()` with a string, specifically, I need to remove `Call()` and replace it with a `'` character. I also need to put a `'` mark at the beginning of `TestFunctionCall()`. So essentially I want to do the following:

`TestFunctionCall() -> 'TestFunction'`

So my final output should look like this:

`md = mod.solver(mod,'TestFunction');`

The problem is, I have many different names for `TestFunction` and although they end in `Call()`, they might have different names (ie. `MySolverCall()`, `HelloWorldCall()`, etc.).

Since all the files I want have the name and extension `test*.txt`, I figured this would be easy enough for `find` and `sed`. So I used the following command:

`find . -type f -name "test*.txt" -exec sed "s/solver(mod,\(.*\)Call()/solver(md,\'\1\'/g" {} \;`

This spits out a ton of text at me with the files I'm editing, and then it does correctly replace `FunctionNameCall()` with `'FunctionName'`, however it only does so in about 10 files before deciding to stop. It seems no matter how many different files I call this command on, it will only edit around 10 files before stopping.

How can I make it edit every file with the name `test*.txt` in the current directory?

Comment: Does `find . -type f -name "test*.txt" -exec  echo {} \;` output all the filenames ?

Comment: @123 Yep :( I have a feeling it can't handle all the output from `sed` maybe?

Comment: Shouldn't matter how much output as it's all sent straight to STDOUT.

Comment: @Alex I suppose you have files in sub-folders, hence using `find`.. else they can be given directly `sed 'command' test*.txt` .. second, can you just manually copy few files (more than 10) to another folder and see if it works

Comment: Could you try with it `find .... -exec sed 's/.../.../g' '{}' >> /path/to/huge/output.txt` just to see if the problem is with the output to screen or something else? Use also `set -x` before you issue `find`.

Comment: Does it stop always on the same file? How long does it take before it stops? What does `ulimit -a` return? What is the exit status?